# Is there a way to check for @Output wire up from within a component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

In the `ngOnInit` method of a component the `@Input` values will have been bound so you can check those properties on the component, but there doesn't seem to be a way to check `@Output` event bindings. I want to be able to know if the `@Output` was wired up on the component or not.

(using Angular and TypeScript)

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'sample',
    template: `<p>a sample</p>`
})
export class SampleComponent {
    @Output() cancel = new EventEmitter();
    
    ngOnInit() {
        // would like to check and see if cancel was used
        // on the element <sample (cancel)="doSomething()"></sample> 
        // or not <sample></sample>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Same approach as [user1448982](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1448982/user1448982) but without using the `ObservableWrapper` that is meant to be platform code that is not exposed for use via the api.

(Using Angular 2 RC1 and TypeScript)
*Note: This only started working from 2.0.0-beta.16 and greater*

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'sample',
    template: `<p>a sample</p>`
})
export class SampleComponent {
    @Output() cancel = new EventEmitter();
    private isCancelUsed = false;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isCancelUsed = this.cancel.observers.length > 0;
    }
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bhDUWF?p=info)

The `ObservableWrapper.hasSubscribers` method does this line internally, so you can just do the same thing here.

*When using TypeScript you will get a transpile time error if Angular ever ends up changing the `EventEmitter` from a `Subject` (which is part `Observable`, thus the `.observers` property).*

#### Update (03 / 2022)

The `observers` attribute is deprecated since [rxjs v7](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/commit/14cc6855ae225b5197b49cec7700f80ee18241f4#diff-7f7e94a90972125afeece1b98180e2ae67c8e21b242fb30d9ed88f330c227b1aR18-R19). Instead of checking the length of the observers array, you can now use a boolean that indicates if the subject is in use.

```js
// Old approach
this.isCancelUsed = this.cancel.observers.length > 0;

// New approach
this.isCancelUsed = this.cancel.observed;
```

Comment: The `observed` property is a really neat, clean solution to this.

Answer (score 4):

Angular 12 removed the `EventEmitter#observables` field so the accepted answer is no longer valid.

An alternative solution for now would be to cast to a Subject instead:

```
get hasOutputEventSubscriber() {
    return (this.cancel as Subject).observers;
}
```

Note that this property is also deprecated and will be removed in rxjs v8. A future-proof solution would be to write a custom wrapper class for the EventEmitter.

Comment: you can use `this.cancel.observed`, which is a getter property which wraps the now deprecated method

Answer (score 3):

The following code should work:

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {ObservableWrapper} from 'angular2/src/facade/async';

@Component({
    selector: 'sample',
    template: `<p>a sample</p>`
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() cancel: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    private isCancelUsed: boolean;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.isCancelUsed = ObservableWrapper.hasSubscribers(this.cancel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't rely on this though. The Angular team doesn't make any guarantees that `EventEmitter` will continue to extends `Observable`

Comment: However now we are in 2021 and it appears very highly unlikely that this will ever be changed. Observables are everywhere in Angular and are here to stay. They totally make sense as output event emitters. I think if they really wanted us to completely avoid using observable features they'd have exposed an Observable instance yes, but as a subsetted interface that only allows for emit/subscribe.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a future proof example that does not rely on any internals of Angular or rxjs. This is a simple wrapper around `EventEmitter` that exposes a `subscriberCount` property that is automatically incremented/decremented as subscribers are added/removed.

```js
class WatchedEventEmitter extends EventEmitter<any> {
    private _subscriberCount = 0;
    get subscriberCount(): number {
        return this._subscriberCount;
    }

    subscribe(next?: (value: any) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription {
        ++this._subscriberCount;
        return super.subscribe(next, error, complete);
    }

    unsubscribe() {
        --this._subscriberCount;
        super.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```js
@Component({template: `
    {{click.subscriberCount|json}}
    <span *ngIf="cancel.subscriberCount">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="cancel.emit()">Click Me</button>
    </span>
    
    <span *ngIf="!cancel.subscriberCount">No Subscribers</span>
`})
export class SomeComponent {
    @Output() cancel = new WatchedEventEmitter();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as of now current version Angular 13 to check if is there any observer/callback is provided you can use `this.cancel.observed` which will return `boolean`

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'sample',
    template: `<p>a sample</p>`
})
export class SampleComponent {
    @Output() cancel = new EventEmitter();
    private isCancelUsed = false;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isCancelUsed = this.cancel.observed;
    }
}
```